# How to format repeater control with ul and li tags

Tags: html, asp.net

i need to format the aspx like this with the help of repeater control

```
<div id="gallery">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <h5>Image title 1</h5>
                    <a href="gallery/1.jpg" title="Des 2">
                    <img src="gallery/1.jpg" alt="Image 01" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h5>Image Title 2</h5>
                    <a href="gallery/2.jpg" title="Des 2">
                    <img src="gallery/2.jpg" alt="Image 02" />
                    </a>
                </li>
               </ul>
</div>
```

My repeater code is like this

```
<div id="gallery">
          <asp:repeater id="repeater1" runat="server">
              <itemtemplate>
                  <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageThumbPath") %>' 
                  Width="100px" Height="80px" alt='<%#Eval("ImageName") %>' style="cursor:pointer" />
              </itemtemplate>                  
          </asp:repeater>
      </div>
```

My Database contain fields
ImageName
ImageThumbPath
ImageTitle
ImageDescription

How can i achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start your `ul` tag in `HeaderTemplate` and `li` will be added in `ItemTemplate` and close tour `ul` tag in `FooterTemplate`..like shown below:

```
<div id="gallery">
<asp:Repeater id="repeater1" runat="server">

     <HeaderTemplate>
     <ul>
     </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
      <li>
        <h5><%# Eval("ImageTitle") %></h5>
         <a href="<%# Eval("ImageThumbPath") %>">
           <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageThumbPath") %>' />                   
         </a>
      </li>
    </ItemTemplate>  

     <FooterTemplate>
      </ul>
     </FooterTemplate>  

</asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to repeat all of the Html which needs to be emitted for each item in the `ItemTemplate`, and the static wrapper part outside of the repeater, something like:

```
<div id="gallery">
  <ul>
    <asp:Repeater ID="repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <li>
            <h5><%# Eval("ImageTitle") %></h5>
             <a href="<%# Eval("ImageThumbPath") %>">
               <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageThumbPath") %>' 
                   Width="100px" Height="80px" alt='<%#Eval("ImageName") %>' />
             </a>
          </li>
        </ItemTemplate>                  
    </asp:Repeater>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note the capitalization issues with the controls in your code.